# Tengo un problema la momento de generar un nuevo aleatorio y entrar a un actionperformed y recorrer unos for e if

Tags: java-swing

EL programa es sencillo el usuario escoge un boton para saber si atrapa un cardumen si lo captura debo enviar un mensaje y si falla veo si el cardumen se encontraba cerca de donde presiono el boton si lo esta movilizo el cardumen y le informo al usuario donde se encuentra la posicion del cardumen (por las direcciones cardinales) pero no esta entrando como deberia... puedo mostrar la posicion del cardumen y reiniciar el contador de intentos pero no mas de ahí. anexo el codigo para que puedan echarle un ojo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DiegoCaballeros();
}

DiegoCaballeros() {
    ventana = new JFrame("Pesca");// se crea la ventana
    ventana.setBounds(200, 200, 925, 600);
    ventana.setLayout(null);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)// creamos e imprimimos los 100 botones
    {
        btn_boton = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));// se le da un valor del 0 al 99 el cual aparecera en la ventana
        btn_boton.setBounds(150 + 45 * (i % 10), 70 + 40 * (i / 10), 50, 30);
        // btn_boton.addActionListener(this);
        ventana.add(btn_boton);
    }

    int x = 1, y = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)// creamos la numeracion vertical
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80
                || i == 90)// evaluamos para la impresion
        {
            lbl_numeros = new JLabel(String.valueOf(x));// se le da un valor del 0 al 99 el cual aparecera en la
                                                        // ventana
            lbl_numeros.setBounds(130 + 45 * (i % 1), 70 + 40 * (i / 10), 50, 30);
            ventana.add(lbl_numeros);
            x++;
        }
        if (i == 90 || i == 91 || i == 92 || i == 93 || i == 94 || i == 95 || i == 96 || i == 97 || i == 98
                || i == 99)// evaluamos para la impresion
        {
            lbl_numeros = new JLabel(String.valueOf(y));// se le da un valor del 0 al 99 el cual aparecera en la
                                                        // ventana
            lbl_numeros.setBounds(150 + 45 * (i % 10), 100 + 40 * (i / 10), 50, 30);
            ventana.add(lbl_numeros);
            y++;
        }
    }

    btn_reiniciar = new JButton("REINICIAR PESCA");
    btn_reiniciar.setBounds(300, 10, 150, 20);
    btn_reiniciar.addActionListener(this);
    ventana.add(btn_reiniciar);

    btn_mostrar = new JButton("MOSTRAR");
    btn_mostrar.setBounds(575, 10, 100, 20);
    btn_mostrar.addActionListener(this);
    ventana.add(btn_mostrar);

    btn_pesca = new JButton("TIRAR RED");
    btn_pesca.setBounds(700, 30, 120, 20);
    btn_pesca.addActionListener(this);
    ventana.add(btn_pesca);

    tf_pesca = new JTextField("");
    tf_pesca.setBounds(700, 10, 50, 20);
    ventana.add(tf_pesca);

    lbl_intentos = new JLabel("intentos");
    lbl_intentos.setBounds(25, 10, 120, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_intentos);

    tf_intentos = new JTextField("0");
    tf_intentos.setBounds(70, 10, 30, 20);
    ventana.add(tf_intentos);

    lbl_norte = new JLabel("NORTE");// arriba
    lbl_norte.setBounds(350, 45, 120, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_norte);

    lbl_sur = new JLabel("SUR");// abajo
    lbl_sur.setBounds(370, 500, 120, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_sur);

    lbl_oeste = new JLabel("OESTE");// izquierda
    lbl_oeste.setBounds(80, 250, 120, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_oeste);

    lbl_este = new JLabel("ESTE");// derecha
    lbl_este.setBounds(615, 250, 120, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_este);

    /*
     * btn_iniciar = new JButton("INICIAR ALEATORIO");
     * btn_iniciar.setBounds(300, 525, 150, 20);
     * btn_iniciar.addActionListener(this);
     * ventana.add(btn_iniciar);
     */

    lbl_universidad = new JLabel("Universidad Tecnologica de Panama");
    lbl_universidad.setBounds(675, 150, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_universidad);

    lbl_facultad = new JLabel("Facultad de Sistemas y Computacion");
    lbl_facultad.setBounds(675, 175, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_facultad);

    lbl_carrera = new JLabel("Lic. en Desarrollo de Software");
    lbl_carrera.setBounds(675, 200, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_carrera);

    lbl_materia = new JLabel("Materia Desarrollo de Software III");
    lbl_materia.setBounds(675, 225, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_materia);

    lbl_profesor = new JLabel("Profesor Ricardo Chan");
    lbl_profesor.setBounds(675, 250, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_profesor);

    lbl_nombre = new JLabel("Estudiante Diego Caballero");
    lbl_nombre.setBounds(675, 275, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_nombre);

    lbl_cedula = new JLabel("8-911-1979");
    lbl_cedula.setBounds(675, 300, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_cedula);

    lbl_salon = new JLabel("1LS221");
    lbl_salon.setBounds(675, 325, 250, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_salon);

    lbl_fecha = new JLabel("Fecha de entrega 8 de junio de 2022");
    lbl_fecha.setBounds(675, 350, 300, 20);
    ventana.add(lbl_fecha);

    cardumen = new Random();

    // si profesor no me se los puntos cardinales bien por si llega a leer esto

    ventana.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    btn_temp = (JButton) e.getSource();// variable temporal que sera usada para evaluar el uso de los 100 botones y
                                       // todos los demas botones
    JFrame mensaje = new JFrame();
    int noreste[], noroeste[], sureste[], suroeste[];
    noreste = new int[25];
    noroeste = new int[25];
    sureste = new int[25];
    suroeste = new int[25];
    int x = 0, peces = 0;

    if (x == 0) {
        peces = (cardumen.nextInt(99 - 0 + 1) + 0);
        /*
         * cardumen = ((int)(Math.random()*(99-0+1)+0));
         * 
         * private Random cardumen = new Random();
         * int cardumen;
         * cardumen = ((int)(Math.random()*(99-0+1)+0)); // generamos un numero random
         * del 0 al 99 para ubicar al cardumen
         * cardumen = (rnd.nextInt(99-0+1)+0);
         * cardumen=(rnd.nextInt(99-0+1)+0);
         * 
         * // cardumen = (rnd.nextInt(99)); // generamos de forma global el cardumen
         * // alatorio de 0 a 99
         */
        x = 1;
    }

    tf_intentos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tf_intentos.getText()) + 1));

    if (btn_temp == btn_mostrar) // mensaje de pantalla
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "El cardumen se encuentra en la posicion: " + peces);
    }

    if (btn_temp == btn_reiniciar)// mensaje de pantalla
    {
        tf_intentos.setText("0");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "Usted reinicio el juego");
    }
    // btn_temp = Integer.parseInt(btn_temp.getText);
    int planta = Integer.parseInt(tf_pesca.getText());// aqui estamos convirtiendo para poder realizar las
                                                      // evaluaciones
    int plantita = Integer.parseInt(tf_intentos.getText());

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) // cargando los vectores
    {
        noreste[i] = noreste[i] + i;
        if (noreste[i] == 4) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (noreste[i] == 14) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (noreste[i] == 24) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (noreste[i] == 34) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 5; i < 50; i++) // cargando los vectores
    {
        noroeste[i] = noroeste[i] + i;
        if (noroeste[i] == 9) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (noroeste[i] == 19) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (noroeste[i] == 29) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (noroeste[i] == 39) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 50; i < 95; i++)// cargando los vectores
    {
        sureste[i] = sureste[i] + i;
        if (sureste[i] == 54) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (sureste[i] == 64) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (sureste[i] == 74) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (sureste[i] == 84) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 55; i < 100; i++) // cargando los vectores
    {
        suroeste[i] = suroeste[i] + i;
        if (suroeste[i] == 59) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (suroeste[i] == 69) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (suroeste[i] == 79) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
        if (suroeste[i] == 89) {
            i = i + 5;
        }
    }
    if (btn_temp == btn_pesca) 
    {
        if (planta == peces) // evaluamos si el cardumen ah sido atrapado
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "Usted capturo el cardumen");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // aqui se moviliza un for para evaluar la posicion del cardumen y si esta
                                      // cerca
                                      // del cardumen
        {// utilizamos la variable de control i para serciorarnos que este dentro del
         // rango
            if (planta == noreste[i] && peces == noreste[i]) // evaluamos si fallo en la captura y el
                                                             // cardumen esta
            // cerca
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "El cardumen se ah movido");
                while (peces == noreste[i])// aqui mantenemos el ciclo hasta hasta que sea diferente
                {
                    peces = (cardumen.nextInt(99 - 0 + 1) + 0);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // aqui se moviliza un for para evaluar la posicion del cardumen y si esta
                                      // cerca
                                      // del cardumen
        {// utilizamos la variable de control i para serciorarnos que este dentro del
         // rango
            if (planta == noroeste[i] && peces == noroeste[i]) // evaluamos si fallo en la captura y el
                                                               // cardumen
            // esta cerca
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "El cardumen se ah movido");
                while (peces == noroeste[i])// aqui mantenemos el ciclo hasta hasta que sea diferente
                {
                    peces = (cardumen.nextInt(99 - 0 + 1) + 0);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // aqui se moviliza un for para evaluar la posicion del cardumen y si esta
                                      // cerca
                                      // del cardumen
        {// utilizamos la variable de control i para serciorarnos que este dentro del
         // rango
            if (planta == sureste[i] && peces == sureste[i]) // evaluamos si fallo en la captura y el
                                                             // cardumen esta
            // cerca
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "El cardumen se ah movido");
                while (peces == sureste[i])// aqui mantenemos el ciclo hasta hasta que sea diferente
                {
                    peces = (cardumen.nextInt(99 - 0 + 1) + 0);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // aqui se moviliza un for para evaluar la posicion del cardumen y si esta
                                      // cerca
                                      // del cardumen
        {// utilizamos la variable de control i para serciorarnos que este dentro del
         // rango
            if (planta == suroeste[i] && peces == suroeste[i]) // evaluamos si fallo en la captura y el
                                                               // cardumen
            // esta cerca
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "El cardumen se ah movido");
                while (peces == suroeste[i])// aqui mantenemos el ciclo hasta hasta que sea diferente
                {
                    peces = (cardumen.nextInt(99 - 0 + 1) + 0);
                }
            }
        }

        if (planta != peces) // evaluamos si fallo y el cardumen esta lejos
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "Fallo al intentar capturar el cardumen esta lejos todavia");
        }

        if (plantita == 100) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mensaje, "Va por mal camino");
        }

        /*
         * else
         * {
         * for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         * {
         * if (btn_temp != cardumen && btn_temp == i) // evaluamos si fallo en la
         * captura y el cardumen esta cerca
         * {
         * = new JButton("El cardumen se ah movido");
         * .setBounds(150,150,55,100);
         * ventana.ad);
         * }
         * }
         * }
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: Especifica en el título _cuál es el problema_. "Tengo un problema al...." no da indicios rápidos del inconveniente en cuestión. Lee [ask]. ¿El problema es a donde ha* ido el cardumen? ¿No imprime los detalles? ¿No reinicia el contador?